# Optimizing bulk xml data insert in postgresql 9.6

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath, query-optimization

I am currently optimizing an xml parser where I currently have a bottleneck on a bulk insert of 10,000 records into an xml array in postgres. This version of postgres does not implement xmltable. The following code is what I currently have:

```
create unlogged table xmltable(
 xml_element1 xml[],
 xml_element2 xml[],
 xml_element3 xml[]
);

v_xml := XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT convert_from(src_blob, 'UTF8') );

INSERT INTO xmltable ( xml_element1, xml_element2, xml_element3)
     SELECT 
         (xpath ('element1parent/element1feature', x_xml)),
         (xpath ('element2parent/element2feature', x_xml)),
         (xpath ('element3parent/element3feature', x_xml)),
     FROM (SELECT unnest(xpath('/Root/grandparent',v_xml)) as x_xml);

drop table xmltable;


Current processing time is about 4 minutes for xml_element1 = 40 inserts, 
xml_element2 = 9,980 inserts, xml_element3 = 0 inserts.
```

A couple things I've tried are:

Switch between temporary and unlogged table 
Breaking up query 
using v_xml := convert_from(src_blob, 'UTF8')::xml

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the unnest function is unescessary and accumulates alot of overhead.

This was way faster:

```
INSERT INTO xmltable ( xml_element1, xml_element2, xml_element3)
 SELECT 
     (xpath ('/Root/grandparent/element1parent/element1feature', v_xml)),
     (xpath ('/Root/grandparent/element2parent/element2feature', v_xml)),
     (xpath ('/Root/grandparent/element3parent/element3feature', v_xml));
```